# Apply with LinkedIn plugin no longer working

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

My company was using the member plugin from Linkedin (older version, but similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin/awli-plugin)

The script we are using:

`src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"> api_key: 75r1ctnax0op6a`

But it takes me to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize?_l=en_US and return a page not found

[image]

I tried changing to use the one in the docs but the it also doesn't work: "platform.linkedin.com/xdoor/scripts/in.js"

So I tried to use oauth2 API to connect, and it works but the r_liteprofile doesn't return the public url which is what we need, any idea on how I can get that info? Did anyone manage to make the javascript plugin work or was it really disabled?